# Determining type of Wifi connection in Android

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

How do you determine which type of Wifi connection an Android device is currently using?

For example, is the device connected using an 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n, or 802.11ac connection?

Since, for example 802.11n Wifi adapters can connect with 802.11g or 802.11b, I want to know which method is actually used for the connection.

Answers should be compatible with Android KitKat.

Answer (score 3):

If you can check Wi-Fi `Link Speed` It will give you an idea about the current connection.

"Maximum" link speed allowed is as follows-

- `Link speed 866.5Mbps - 802.11ac`
- `Link speed 300Mbps - 802.11n`
- `Link speed 54Mbps - 802.g`
- `Link speed 11Mbps - 802.b`

Also Link speed varies by your signal strength. So check Link speed of connected router in wifi settings, and get a idea. For example link speed shows 86.7, it is 802.11n. If your speed is greater than 130Mbps, it's 802.11n otherwise not. Some standard values for 802.11n are 150Mbps (single stream router) & 300Mbps (2 stream router).

Comment: Thanks! There were some typos, so I tried to clean up your answer a little bit.  I couldn't quite figure out the section around the words "otherwise not".  Maybe you can clarify that a little?